# How to allow wordwrapping along with horizontal scrolling

Tags: html, css

I was trying to implement horizontal scrolling, after a lot of searching I found the solution using

```
.wrapper{
  overflow: auto;
}
.innerWrapper{
  overflow-x: scroll;
  overflow-y: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

This gave me the solution I needed for adding new div elements which adjust horizontally, But what if I have a huge word like `#tagsomething`, I want the word to be broken like

```
.tagLink{
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

this doesn't work as I understand that I am using nowrap on the whole container, is there a way around this?

Check out the code: https://jsfiddle.net/v5s5ema8/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply override it on the child elements.

```
.tags {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qw5m21L4/).

Comment: I could but then my boxes are adjusting according to the words, I want all the boxes to be of the same size

Comment: @TheCodeWatcher No they don't? See the updated fiddle.